# Data structure that allows you to add multiple objects for the same key

Tags: ios, data-structures

I am looking for a data structure that allows me to add multiple objects for the same key.

I have a table that is downloading images and when it finishes downloading an image I want it to set the image in all the cells with that image name.

So I want a data structure where the key is the image name and it multiple objects i.e pointers to the cells.
 
I know I can't do this in NSMutable dictionary as it just overwrites the keys. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a NSDictionary containing a NSMutableArray :

```
NSDictionary *myDico = @{@"imageName":[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]};
```

Where ... = the references to the cells.

*Edit :*

You also can, if you have multiple images, use a NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to copy one array to a new array and add a new object in it?

Comment: NSMutableArray *newArray  = [[oldArray mutableCopy] addObject:newObject];

Answer (score 2):

How about using NSMutableDictionary whose value is a NSMutableArray? You can append the array when new cells are added or check nil and add an empty array when the key is not stored before.

Answer (score 0):

Just use NSArray to add multiple values against single key.

```
NSDictionary *dictt = @{@"imageKey":@[@"image1", @"image2"]};
```